# Pair Class Implementation in Java

Tags: java, sorting

Please brief me about what the use of `compareTo()` function in this code. What is the work it is performing. If we remove `compareTo()` function it gives an error.

I don't know what is the use of `compareTo()` function and how it is affecting the implementation of the code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author rajat
 */
public class ImplementPair {

    public static int mod = (int) (1e9+7);


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
           Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=in.nextInt();
        int k=in.nextInt();
        PriorityQueue<Pair> pq=new PriorityQueue<>();

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int x=in.nextInt();
            pq.add(new Pair(x, i+1));
            System.out.println("prior   "+pq);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            Pair p=pq.poll();
            System.out.println("prior   "+pq);
            pq.add(new Pair(p.x-1, p.y));
            System.out.println("prior   "+pq);
        }


    }

    static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{

        long x,y,i;



    Pair (long x,long y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public int compareTo(Pair o) {

        if(this.x!=o.x)
                {
                    System.out.println(-Long.compare(this.x,o.x));
                    return -Long.compare(this.x,o.x);

                }
        else
                    return Long.compare(this.y,o.y);
        //return 0;
    }




        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return  x + " " + y ;
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: At first it sorts by the value of X. Then if X values are equal it sorts by the value of Y. The negative sign probably affects whether the sort is ascending or descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `PriorityQueue` with natural ordering. From [javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. A priority queue does not permit null elements. **A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).**

If you want to remove `compareTo` (and don't implements `Comparable`) you should use constructor of `PriorityQueue` with `Comparator`

Your `compareTo` implementetion is just descendent order by `x` and ascending order by `y` if `x` are equals.